# Delete files of particular extension except one in Linux

Tags: bash, files, delete

I have files:

```
a.txt
b.txt
e.txt
c.c
d.o
```

I want to delete ONLY `.txt` files excluding `e.txt`, so the files which will remain at the end are:

```
e.txt
c.c
d.o
```

Comment: How to delete executable files which are also present in the same directory adding to above scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

given:

```
cpetro01@<work_laptop> ~/Notes/test
$ ls
a.jpg  a.txt  b.mov  b.txt  c.jpg  c.mov
```

do:

```
$ find ./ -name "*.txt" -not -name "e.txt"
./a.txt
./b.txt
```

thus:

```
cpetro01@<work_laptop> ~/Notes/test
$ ls
a.jpg  a.txt  b.mov  b.txt  c.jpg  c.mov  e.txt

cpetro01@<work_laptop> ~/Notes/test
$ find ./ -name "*.txt" -not -name "e.txt" -exec rm {} \;

cpetro01@<work_laptop> ~/Notes/test
$ ls
a.jpg  b.mov  c.jpg  c.mov  e.txt
```

Like that?

Comment: How to delete executable files which are also present in the same directory adding to above scenario

Comment: Read the "find" man page. It's got all sorts of ways to find files.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

- Using `GLOBIGNORE` variable to indicate the file name(s) that would be ignored while globbing:

  ```
  GLOBIGNORE=e.txt
  rm -- *.txt
  unset GLOBIGNORE
  ```
- Setting `extglob` option, and using extended globbing to match all `.txt` files except `e.txt`:

  ```
  shopt -s extglob
  rm -- !(e).txt
  shopt -u extglob
  ```

Comment: Yes correct, i have a small add on.
How to delete executable files also which are present in the same directory adding to above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This will list all `.txt` files except for `e.txt`:

```
ls -1 *.txt | grep -v '^e.txt$'
```

You can then do [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) to tell `rm` to delete those files:

```
rm $(ls -1 *.txt | grep -v '^e.txt$')
```

Comment: Yes correct, i have a small add on.
How to delete executable files also which are present in the same directory adding to above scenario.